# Rails - Loading assets through the Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to set up asset pipeline on a older rails app that i have so that i can start using CoffeeScript. i am using ruby 1.9.3-p327 and Rails 3.2.13. I used to stash all my JS, CSS and my images in the `public/` folder. This is what i have done so far ->

1. I moved them all to app/assets, i added the manifest files for both JS and CSS call `//= require_tree .`.
2. Added the following gems

   ```
   group :assets do
     gem 'coffee-rails'
     gem 'uglifier'
     gem 'sass-rails'
     gem 'therubyracer'
   end
   ```
3. Removed all my `javascript_include_tags` except for `= javascript_include_tag 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'`
4. Added the following to my `config/application.rb` file

   ```
   # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
   # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
   # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
   # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
   config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

   # Enable the asset pipeline
   config.assets.enabled = true

   # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
   config.assets.version = '1.0'
   ```
5. Within the config/environments/development.rb file set

   ```
   # Do not compress assets
   config.assets.compress = false

   # Expands the lines which load the assets
   config.assets.debug = true
   ```
6. I added to the config/environments/production.rb

   ```
   # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
   config.assets.compress = true

   # Choose the compressors to use
   # config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
   # config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

   # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
   config.assets.compile = false

   # Generate digests for assets URLs.
   config.assets.digest = true

   # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
   # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
   ```

I re-read the section on the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) just to see if i messed up anything. But so far none of the assets are pulling through from `app/assets` the only one that is working is the `jquery.min.js` that i have coming in through `include_tag` i have tried removing it and trying again no dice.

I have tried `bundle exec rake assets:clean`, and `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, both of which run without issues. and have bundled since adding the gems for the assets, and restarted pow each time.

I am not sure if i am going through this all wrong or i have missed a step? any one gone through this before and tips or clues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you removed all the `javascript_include_tag` statements. Assuming you named the manifests `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`, you'll need to include those in your layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Otherwise, Rails won't know to load your manifest files

Also, you shouldn't be using `rake assets:precompile` in development. If you do, then anytime you change a JS/CSS file, you'll have to recompile the assets before your changes show up.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. i assumed that rails would automatically look at each manifest file and then go traverse through the tree. but that wasn't it. all the css looks as if its acting up but i can see that its loading them at least! thank you kind sir